# Error installing mod_wsgi 3.2

Tags: mod-wsgi

I am trying to install mod_wsgi 3.2 on Mac OSX 10.6.6 and am getting this error when I attempt to make

Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/XW/XWYalsEzG3Gkn+PhoNKF0k+++TI/-Tmp-//ccsEgbTa.out (No such file or directory)
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but I found a solution in my searching and wanted to include it here for others.  This error typically occurs because you are trying to build libraries for ppc architecture which won't work as xcode4 doesn't no longer includes support for ppc.  You can get around this by setting the following in your environment before running your build (I put this in my .bash_profile so I don't beat my head against the wall later):

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
```

Comment: That variable is usually only of relevance when building Python extension modules and not mod_wsgi itself. For building mod_wsgi you would edit the generated Makefile and remove the ppc variant of the option from CFLAGS/LDFLAGS.

Answer (score 0):

The latest mod_wsgi version is 3.3 for a start, why are you using 3.2? Second, there is a precompiled mod_wsgi.so binary for MacOS X which can be used for Apple supplied Python and Apache, so you do not need to compile it from source code and so avoid need to have installed XCode development tools. The precompile mod_wsgi.so is available from mod_wsgi download page.

As to the errors, it would appear to be a permissions problem for user that you are compiling as. That or you aren't using standard Apple supplied software and have somehow mixed up your PATH so it is grabbing disparate tools from different package distributions. Are you using just Apple tools or have you installed any of MacPorts, fink or HomeBrew?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Make file like:

```
CPPFLAGS = -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -DNDEBUG 
CFLAGS = -Wc,"-arch i386" -Wc,"-arch x86_64" -Wc
LDFLAGS = -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -F/Library/Frameworks -framework Python -u _PyMac_Error 
LDLIBS = -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question 
In the end,I found I don't have write permission of '**/usr/libexec/apache2/**'
then I add chmod +w to the folder,, 
then install success !!

Hope my answer can be a refer for some others

Good Luck!

Comment: You are meant to do the install step as root using 'sudo' command.

Comment: What has homebrew got to do with it? Basically the directory '/usr/libexec/apache2' can only be written by root. If you are using Apple supplied Apache, which will be the default, then you must do the install as root else the mod_wsgi.so can't be copied into that directory. You have gotten arount it by separate becoming root and making directory writable, which is the wrong way of going about it.